# Wordpress - Show the_excerpt of post on facebook share

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post

i'm looking  a way to display the-excerpt of post when Sharing on facebook, here is my code, but it doenst show the_exceprt of the post . ..

```
   <a <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t= <?php the_excerpt(); ?><?php the_title(); ?>"<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

If it can help, this is the section with the all code ( it's a grid system, each box of the "grid" has different content)

```
<div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half cell tabbed" style="background-color: #ccffff" >
                    <a href="LINK_TO_PRESS_POST"><h1>Press room</h1></a>
                    <?php
                    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'coverage', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <time class="timestamp"><?php the_date(); ?></time>
                    <h2 class="h4"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="palm--hidden"><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p></p></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="palm--hidden">Read More</a>  
                    <div class="social-icons-2">
                        <ul class="hl">
                            <li>Share:</li>
                            <li><a <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t= <?php the_excerpt(); ?><?php the_title(); ?>"<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>

                            <li><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=&nbsp;Take a look<?php the_title(); ?> <?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endwhile; endif; 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
```

ANother question related with this facebook share, at the moment it's sharing the logo of the website . . any possiblity to show insterad the picture attach of the post ?

Thank you so much for all your time in advance

EDIT: I put here all the code of the page in case it heelps . ..

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="slider-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 slider-header-left">
                        WHAT WE DO
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 slider-header-right">
                        texttt
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

<div id="home-slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row home-content-slider">
            <?php 
                $services = get_page_by_path('services');
                if($services) $parent = $services->ID;
                $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_per_page' => 5, 'post_parent' => $parent, 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
                $service_titles = array();
                $service_images = array();
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $i = 1;
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        $service_titles[] = '<li id="nav-fragment-'. $i .'" class=""><a href="#fragment-'. $i .'" ><span>'. get_the_title() .'</span></a></li>';
                        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full' );
                        $service_images[] = '<div id="fragment-'. $i .'" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"><img src="'. $image[0] .'" title="" /><div class="overlay-description">'. get_field('slider_text') .'</div></div>';
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 home-slider-left">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul>
                        <?php echo implode( "\n", $service_titles ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 home-slider-right">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo implode( "\n", $service_images ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div id="grid_container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 news-post" style="background-color: #ccfff"  data-key="newsItem">
            <article class="grid row">
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half">
                    <?php
                    echo '<div class="flexslider">';
                    echo '<ul class="slides">';
                    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'coverage', 'posts_per_page' => 9 ) );
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'homepage-thumb' );
                        if($image) echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'"><img class="img-responsive" src="'. $image[0] .'" alt="" /></a></li>';
                    endwhile; endif; 
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </div>
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half cell tabbed" style="background-color: #ccffff" >
                    <a href="http://LINKK_TO.com/?post_type=coverage"><h1>Press room</h1></a>
                    <?php
                    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'coverage', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <time class="timestamp"><?php the_date(); ?></time>
                    <h2 class="h4"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="palm--hidden"><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p></p></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="palm--hidden">Read More</a>  
                    <div class="social-icons-2">
                        <ul class="hl">
                            <li>Share:</li>
                            <li><a <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t= <?php the_excerpt(); ?><?php the_title(); ?>"<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>

                            <li><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=&nbsp;Take a look<?php the_title(); ?> <?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endwhile; endif; 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 news-post" style="background-color: #ffcccc"  data-key="newsItem">
            <article class="grid row">
                <?php
                $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half">
                    <figure data-ratio="1">
                        <?php
                        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'homepage-thumb' );
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img width="640" height="640" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" /></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half cell tabbed" style="background-color: #ffcccc" >
                                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1>NEWS</h1></a>
                    <time class="timestamp"><?php the_date(); ?></time>
                    <h2 class="h4"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="palm--hidden"><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="palm--hidden">Read More</a>  
                    <div class="social-icons-2">
                        <ul class="hl">
                            <li>Share:</li>
                            <li><a href="SM1" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="sm2" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="sm3" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                endwhile; endif; 
                ?>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 news-post" style="background-color: #ffffff"  data-key="newsItem">
            <article class="grid row">
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item one-half">
                    <figure data-ratio="1">
                     <!-- SnapWidget -->
<!-- SnapWidget -->
<!-- SnapWidget -->
<iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/sc/?u=aW5fc3BhY2VzfGlufDI4MHwzfDN8fG5vfDV8bm9uZXx8eWVzfG5v&ve=020914" title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:295px; height:295px"></iframe>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half cell tabbed twitter-widget" style="background-color: #ffffff" >
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="sm2" data-widget-id="501148708545638400">Tweets by @In__Spaces</a>
                    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="post-1410 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-news col-sm-6 news-post" style="background-color: #ffffcc"  data-key="newsItem">
            <article class="grid row">
                <?php
                $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half">
                    <figure data-ratio="1">
                        <?php
                        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'homepage-thumb' );
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img width="640" height="640" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" /></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div data-ratio="1" class="grid__item grid__item_inline one-half cell tabbed" style="background-color: #ffffcc" >
                                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1>EVENTS</h1></a>
                    <time class="timestamp">August 22, 2014</time>
                    <h2 class="h4"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="palm--hidden"><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="palm--hidden">Read More</a>  
                    <div class="social-icons-2">
                        <ul class="hl">
                            <li>Share:</li>
                            <li><a href="" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                endwhile; endif; 
                ?>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="big-link">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- #main -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Open Graph Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) in the `<head>` section of your page.

Here's an example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=the_title();?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=the_excerpt();?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=the_permalink();?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YOUR_SITE_NAME" />
```

Comment: Hm, If I addd this in my header.php it dsiplay me all teh social media icon, and doesnt show the excerpt still . ..  i don't need the official icon as I need to use some personnal icon for the sharing .. .  If you have any solution ? Thank you :)

Comment: I've add the all code of the page in case it help you

Comment: I didn't say put it in the `header.php` file, I said the head of the HTML document, wherever that is contained. I think you need to look into reading up on the Wordpress Codex.